# Delete element from multidimensional array based on key in C

Tags: c

I am trying to implement a Queue. However I want it so that when I delete from the queue, it removes the element with the highest priority. That means for example if I insert the following values:

```
Value      key       
1000        2 
9000        3
1000        2
```

it should first remove the element with the highest key (in this case 3) and if there are two elements with the same key value then it should remove the one that was inserted earlier.

Note: the 2nd dimension is only 2

```
del(){
    if (front == -1 || front > rear)
    {
        printf("Queue Underflow\n");
        return ;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Element deleted from queue is : %d\n", queue_arr[front][2]);
        front=front+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you implementing this queue? Is it a bounded queue? I'm not quite sure how your array is multidimensional. What exactly is your issue? Please provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a maximum-[priority-queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue), which is normally implemented using a [heap data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29).

The priorities of elements in the queue would be `<your key, insertion order>`, with `your key` part having more priority over `insertion order`.

Comment: I insert a value and the priority key together, as the example above. for example array[value][Key] the value let say 2011 and the key is 2 so when i want to remove any element in the array the value with the highest key will be removed first. in the case the there is 2 or 3 keys in the array with the same value let say 1991 the key is 3 and 2011 the key is also 3 and 1987 the key is also 3 then the value inserted earlier will be removed. i hope it is much clear now thanks again for your support.

Comment: Like I said, that is a priority queue. In a priority queue, you insert values in whatever order you want and when you remove from it, it gives you items according to their priority (or key if you like).

Comment: And it being bounded is dependent on your implementation. You can implement a heap on a fixed (or dynamic length) array fairly easily, or you can completely make it dynamic by allocating memory for each node (although it is usually implemented with the array method)